# using jquery to select an option in a select based on a user-defined variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Given a user-defined variable `jstatus`, I want that that particular variable should be selected in a given list of options.

My list is like this:

```
<select name='job_status' id='job_status'>
    <option>Pre-press</option>
    <option>Printers</option>
    <option>Cutting</option>
    <option>Final touches</option>
    <option>Delivery</option>
    <option>Ready</option>
</select>
```

And somewhere in my javascript code after setting the value of `jstatus`, this is my jquery:

```
$("#job_status option[value='"+jstatus+"']").attr('selected','selected');
```

But it's not working. What's the right way to do it?

Comment: Please, provide `value` attribute to each `<option>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your select list has no "value"-property on its options

```
<select name='job_status' id='job_status'>
     <option value="val1">Pre-press</option>
     <option value="val2">Printers</option>
     <option value="val3">Cutting</option>
     <option value="val4">Final touches</option>
     <option value="val5">Delivery</option>
     <option value="val6">Ready</option>
</select>

<script>
    $( 'select option[value="val3"]' ).attr( 'selected', 'selected' );
</script>
```

You can also use jQuery's val() method

`$( 'select' ).val( 'val3' )`

this would have the same effect as the above

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way is to set the value directly:

```
jQuery("#job_status").val(jstatus);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add value to  selector first.

```
<option value="Pre-press">Pre-press</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you still prefer using a direct selector, there's :contains for you to select element by its contents. For your case it goes pretty much like this:

```
$("#job_status option:contains("+jstatus+")").attr('selected','selected');
```